# VLAN not working on PFSense (SG 1100) with HP switch (HP E3500-48G-PoE yl)

Tags: hp, switch, vlan, pfsense

Recently I bought a PFSense server (SG 1100) and a HP switch (HP E3500-48G-PoE yl). My idea is to create VLANs on the PFSense server, and use them on the connected HP switch.

I have found a tutorial which helped me set up (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2w1Ywt081o). However if I connect a device to the port which I configured as the VLAN it does not get an IP lease.

PFSense configuration:
Created VLAN under interfaces > VLANs
[image]
Added the appropriate interface under interfaces > assignments
[image]
Enabled the DHCP server for the VLAN interface
[image]
Added the firewall rules, in order for it to have internet access
[image]
Since I was not 100% sure, I also added the VLAN to the switch section under interfaces > switches (I copied the configuration of LAN since that is the port where the switch is connected to)
[image]

HP Switch configuration:

```
Running configuration:

; J8693A Configuration Editor; Created on release #K.16.02.0026
; Ver #10:08.03.81.30.02.34.59.2c.6b.ff.f7.fc.7f.ff.3f.ef:26
hostname "HP-Switch-3500yl-48G"
module 1 type j86yya
module 2 type j86xxa
trunk 1 trk1 trunk
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   no untagged 33
   untagged 2-32,34-48,Trk1
   ip address dhcp-bootp
   exit
vlan 2
   name "VTest"
   untagged 33
   no ip address
   exit
spanning-tree Trk1 priority 4
```

I also tried to set the IP config of vlan 2 to dhcp but that didn't work either.

If I connect a PC to port 2-32 / 34-48 it gets an IP address of the LAN configuration of PFSense. However if I connect a PC to port 33 it won't get an IP address assigned. I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I contacted Netgate, who helped me out. All the settings are correct except the part I was not sure about.

You have to go to interfaces > switches > VLANs tab, and add your VLAN and **tag both** 0 (default) and 2 (LAN).
[image]

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. Thank you. No tutorial videos even show this step. Must be something specific to the SG-1100

Comment: I concur - I've had the _exact_ same experience with an SG-1100 and HP ProCurve 1810g-24 J9803A, and had performed the exact same steps before finding this. Adding the extra switch tag solved the issue.

I'd appreciate an explanation of what this is doing if anyone reading this happens to know? I've performed this same task on an SG-3100 and virtualised pfSense instance (neither of which have the switch options) and this wasn't necessary.